# TYPO3 Bootstrap_package translate constants

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typo3, typoscript

I'm using the bootstrap_package of benjamin knott with TYPO3 V11.5.26 and the introduction package, I'm trying to use it multilingual but cannot find where to override `{theme.copyright.text}` which is used in the fluidtemplate ...

I find it once defined in `constants.typoscript` as `page.theme.copyright.text` but then nowhere in the setup that constant asigned to the variable used in fluid ...

**So far this didn't work**: in my own extension I added the constants with the configuration:

```
page {
    theme {
        copyright {
            # cat=bootstrap package: copyright/169/122; type=string; label=Copyright Text Danisch
            da = Kører med <a href="http://www.typo3.org" rel="noopener" target="_blank">TYPO3</a> und <a href="https://www.bootstrap-package.it" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Bootstrap-pakke</a>.
            # cat=bootstrap package: copyright/169/123; type=string; label=Copyright Text German
            de = Läuft mit <a href="http://www.typo3.org" rel="noopener" target="_blank">TYPO3</a> und <a href="https://www.bootstrap-package.it" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Bootstrap-Paket</a>.
        }
    }
    fluidtemplate {
        # cat=bootstrap package: templates/100/100; type=string; label=Layout Root Path: Path to layouts
        layoutRootPath = EXT:bootstrap_package_ext/Resources/Private/Layouts/Page/
        # cat=bootstrap package: templates/100/110; type=string; label=Partial Root Path: Path to partials
        partialRootPath = EXT:bootstrap_package_ext/Resources/Private/Partials/Page/
        # cat=bootstrap package: templates/100/120; type=string; label=Template Root Path: Path to templates
        templateRootPath = EXT:bootstrap_package_ext/Resources/Private/Templates/Page/
    }
}
```

and the override of the variable in the setup:

```
[siteLanguage("twoLetterIsoCode") == "da"]
    page.10.dataProcessing.1.theme.copyright.text = {$page.theme.copyright.da}
[siteLanguage("twoLetterIsoCode") == "de"]
    page.10.dataProcessing.1.theme.copyright.text = {$page.theme.copyright.de}
[END]
```

I could try to extend the class `ConstantsProcessor` which has no localization programmed yet, it does just straightforward turn all the constanst `page` into variables for fluid without further logic, otherwise I can make the language available for fluidtemplate  and bring the logic to the template (working but not clean, Benjamin Knott prides himself on the best practices, so I am keen to find the right solution)

Answer (score 0):

You must override this constant either in your own TS constants file (In your provider extension i.e.) or in the constants section in your page template in the backend.
Described here:
https://docs.typo3.org/p/bk2k/bootstrap-package/13.0/en-us/Configuration/TypoScript/Index.html#page-theme-copyright

If you need different copyrights for multiple languages you can effort this by using TS-Conditions. Described here:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/Conditions/Index.html#sitelanguage

The reason why you can't find a TS setup where the constant is assigned, is because the constant is processed by the ConstantProcessor:
EXT:bootstrap_package/Classes/DataProcessing/ConstantsProcessor.php

If you hook in there with your debugger, you will see that somewhen the copyright constant will be saved to the processedData-array.
Not sure when exactly this array is passed to the fluid-template. But that shouldn't be important at this point.

**Example (Adapted to your code)**

TypoScript Constants:

```
[siteLanguage("twoLetterIsoCode") == "dk"]
    page.theme.copyright.text = Kører med <a href="http://www.typo3.org" rel="noopener" target="_blank">TYPO3</a> und <a href="https://www.bootstrap-package.it" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Bootstrap-pakke</a>.
[siteLanguage("twoLetterIsoCode") == "de"]
    page.theme.copyright.text = Läuft mit <a href="http://www.typo3.org" rel="noopener" target="_blank">TYPO3</a> und <a href="https://www.bootstrap-package.it" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Bootstrap-Paket</a>.
[END]
```

Comment: thanks, but I added what I already tried before posting, i would expect somewhere a 'best practice' solution ...

Comment: You must only override the copyright in the TS Constants. Nothing to do in TS Setup.
I added a code example to my answer.

Comment: surprising that the conditions work in the constants file but... it takes away the chance to handle them as variables, hardcoded is not the correct option !

Comment: "Conditions are a TypoScript syntax construct. They are thus available in both frontend TypoScript and backend TSconfig." as mentioned in the TYPO3 docs here:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/Configuration/TypoScript/Syntax/Conditions/Index.html

Why should you want to handle the copyright-text as variable in TS setup?
I'm with you that localization in TS is not the best way of doing things. IMMO it would be better using language files.
But at the moment this is the only and correct way to do it.
You could ask the dev to implement it in the way you like.

Comment: 1) the bootstrap-package makes the copyright available as editable variable in constants ... 2) normal TYPO3 core behavior (instead of constant proccesor class) makes my setup perfectly workable ... you just define copyright as a variable in the fluidtemplate (as TEXT and then declaring the value)

Comment: I thought your setup isn't working. So why do you talk about a perfectly workable setup? :-)
Until now this is the only and correct answer on how to translate the copyright.
Otherwise go to: https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package/issues and report an issue.